# how to check my internet access on my application android

Tags: android, networking

there's one menu on my application, only can open with internet connection, i have try to put some sources code, but it doesn't work... can anybody help me..?
this is my source code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] listpeta = new String[] { "TMII","Anjungan", "Museum", "Tempat Ibadah","Taman","Wahana Rekreasi"};
    //Menset nilai array ke dalam list adapater sehingga data pada array akan dimunculkan dalam list
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listpeta));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //Menangkap nilai text yang dklik
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    final String keyword = o.toString();
    //Menampilkan list peta.


        final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ListPeta.this, "Loading", "Mohon Tunggu...!!!", true);
        new Thread() { 
              public void run() { 
                   try{
                       Thread.sleep(1000); 
                       if(keyword=="TMII"){petapa="tmii";}
                       else if(keyword=="Anjungan"){petapa="anjungan";}
                       else if(keyword=="Museum"){petapa="museum";} 
                       else if(keyword=="Tempat Ibadah"){petapa="tempatibadah";}
                       else if(keyword=="Taman"){petapa="taman";}
                       else if(keyword=="Wahana Rekreasi"){petapa="rekreasi";}

                       Intent slide2 = new Intent(ListPeta.this, FormPetaTmiiOnline.class);
                       startActivity(slide2);
                   } catch (Exception e) {  } 
                   // Dismiss the Dialog
                   myProgressDialog.dismiss(); 
              } 
         }.start();

}
```

if there's someone help me and give me a source code.. tell me where i must put it on my source code... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to check connectivity:

```
final ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
    //being here means you are connected
} else {
    //being here means you are not connected
}
```

And also include this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

So you can set a boolean to true or false depending on connectivity and use it to determine if you should open the menu or not.

Comment: i have try to use that.. but i still doesn't know where i must to put it

Comment: i read it... i mean.. where i must to put that source code on my source code?

Comment: Inside your onCreate or anywhere you want before you check connectivity to open your menu!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the check the `internet connection`.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
             // your code here(Toast)
    return false;

}
```

And include this `permission` in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

and call this metod before the `setContentView`.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isOnline();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```